# How can I use util object in PeerJS

Tags: javascript, webrtc, peerjs

I'm using PeerJS for a video conferencing application. And I need to use `util.supports.audioVideo` to check if the browser support WebRTC audio and video features.

The PeerJS documentaiton doesn't says how to import util object. I tried to import util from PeerJS, and these are not worked for me.

```
import Peer, { util } from 'peerjs' // Getting util as an interface
import { util } from 'peerjs/lib/util' // Getting webpack loader error
```

Answer (score 2):

After importing 'Peer' or using a CDN, you can access the util object via ***window***.

```
console.log(window.peerjs.util);
```

Using it with ***typescript*** could look like this:

```
import { util } from 'peerjs';

declare global {
  interface Window {
    peerjs: { util: util };
  }
}
```